# Is it possible to write a python script that passively sends wifi speeds and other such information to google sheets or an email?

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to write a python script that passively sends wifi speeds and other such information to google sheets or an email? If so can you please send it to me.(Mac OS)

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

For finding the Wifi speed, you can use [pyspeedtest](https://pypi.org/project/pyspeedtest/). 
You can find the upload/download speed of your network.

**Usage**:

```py
import pyspeedtest

st = pyspeedtest.SpeedTest()
st.download() # 42762976.92544772
st.upload() # 19425388.307319913
```

For sending email, you can use [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html)
For usage, refer [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/send-mail-gmail-account-using-python/)

Further, to automate these two things, you will have to write a script that periodically checks the Wifi speed and sends an email accordingly.

Comment: If I were to not want it to be sent to my email, how would I make it run the script abouve every 15 minutes. Thanks (im new)

Comment: You don't need to send an email to start the script. You can use **cronjob** to make your script run periodically after a specific time. You can refer to this: https://www.jessicayung.com/automate-running-a-script-using-crontab/